# How to just calculate the last number that we just input?

Tags: java

Example we input 20182391, how to just calculate the last digit of number? like "add the last digit with 2"
Thank you

Comment: if `x` is an integer, then `x % 10` gives you the least significant decimal digit.

Comment: do you mean `n%10` ?

Comment: it should be 1 + 2''

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int input = sc.nextInt();
int lastDigit = input % 10;
//Do whatever you want to.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer input = 20182391;
        System.out.println(input % 10 + 2);
    }
```

This should work